# Issues regarding field types in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I want to make a user registration form in Django. While creating model, I gave a fieldtype->PasswordField() to password field but when I run this model into terminal I got a error

```
password=models.PasswordField()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PasswordField'
```

So I want to know that which field type is used for password in Django.I already refer to form doc but I found nothing.

so please help me

Comment: Once again, I *do* hope you're not re-implementing a user model without thinking very very carefully about how you store passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Theory

1. **Use django.db.models.CharField**, since this is an OK database column type for a password string
2. **Use django.forms.PasswordWidget**, to represent this field in a form, see [overriding default form field widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

#### Example

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class YourModel(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from models import YourModel


class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordField}
        model = YourModel
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `PasswordField()` in django. You can to use `CharField()` to store a password, but to show it as password input type in a html form you can specify a widget to it.

Example:

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

More reference at :[PasswordInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput)