# Issues regarding form and view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues regarding field types in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137839/issues-regarding-field-types-in-django)

I am making a User registration form in Django,but the password field shows the password in its original format,I wanted it in dot format.
The coding is not completed yet,but it is enough to do the work which I want.
so please sort out my problem.

the code of model.py is

```
from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


    class Registration(models.Model):
        first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        user_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        password=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        retype_password=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        date_of_reg=models.DateTimeField('date published')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.first_name
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.user_name   
        def was_published_recently(self):
                return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

the code of form.py is

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from models import Registration


    class RegistrationForm(forms.Maniupulator):
        def_init_(self):
           self.fields=(
              forms.PasswordField(field_name='password',
                                    is_required=True),
                  forms.PasswordField(field_name='retype_password',                              
                    is_required=True,
                                    validator_list=[validators.AlwaysMatchesOtherField('password',
                                                                                    'Passwords must match.')]),
            )
```

and view.py is

```
from demo.registration.forms import Registration
from demo.registration.forms import RegistrationForm
```

Comment: How is this question different from your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137839/issues-regarding-field-types-in-django ?

Comment: I asked earlier question during R&D on Registration form and I used your suggestion but that does not work.It is different from my earlier question because now I am working on it practically and now I am  providing  the entire code,because if their is any error in coding part you peoples can figure it out and help me.

Comment: as explained in that question, you need to use `PasswordInput` widget, which you don't seem to be using.

Comment: like that


from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from models import Registration


class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
 
 password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

Comment: If I try to  change anything in forms.py it doesn't effected models.py file or my app.So it means my app is not connected to forms.py

Comment: You may want to go through django tutorial, start with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Thanks buddy !!!!!

I really appreciate your suggestion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15847/discussion-between-neeraj-and-rohan)